# Application made in Visual Studio takes very long to start up

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I wrote an app in Visual Studio and is about 20k+ lines, but I don't know why it takes so long to start up. I have a splash screen just to test it to see if the program is working, and it is, but I have to wait for so long for the app to actually get to the start up form. A splash screen for this app isn't ideal, but was only using a splash screen for test purposes. Any ideas? Language is VB. It has 7 forms excluding the splash screen form.

Comment: Lines 1500-2000 look very questionable to me.

Comment: I'd start with how to write a quesiton. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Because there can be a million different reasons for it being slow.  The question cannot be answered with the information you've given.  You need to narrow it down yourself through debugging to find where the bottleneck is.

Comment: OK, now that could have been an answer, "You need to narrow it down yourself through debugging to find where the bottleneck is." Thanks

Comment: Please give some information about your New() and From_Load() procedures. what they do, which functions they are calling? it's better to place the source code of those procedures in your question.

Comment: @ Mahdi the form1_load is really long, however it used to run fine, not my CPU either (i7 930 @ 4ghz), but somehow when I try to debug it, the app runs but form1 takes very long to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use NGEN and the GAC, however the subject is complex. You will find a good article from Microsoft on this subject [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163610.aspx).

Usually your assemblies (exe's, dll's) contain IL code (Intermediate Language code). When you start the program this code is compiled just in time (it is jitted). NGEN will compile your assemblies to native code (Pentium code).

The GAC is the global assembly cache. If you put your NGENed code there, this will increase startup.

Comment: Found out what was wrong, thanks, but that part wasn't giving me a problem before. I was accessing a ListBox on form2 from form1. And weirdly removing that snippet of code made the program run much faster, like how it was before.